# Zoom on imageView not possible when override onDraw method

Tags: android, imageview, ondraw

I used imageView to display DICOM image. Recently there are a request to put ability to draw Line, rectangle, or free hand draw into the image.

I've read several article and come into conclusion that I should override onDraw method of imageView.

After I do this, I got another problem, I can't zoom those image.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You should give more information, such as the type of dicom file (SOPClassUID) you are trying to draw. Are you able to show a dicom image on your device?

Comment: Yes i've be able to display to display dicom object on my device. The image that i've displayed come from CT modality.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the zoom and pinch in the onDraw method. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html